# Explanation for basic linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list

I am trying to understand a basic example of a linked list in C, but I'm having trouble understanding how they are linked together. Say I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    char s[50];
    struct node* next;
};

struct node* addNode(struct node* head, char s[]);

int main(void)
{
    struct node *head = NULL;
    char* text[] = {"one", "two", "three",
                    "four", "five", "six"};
    int i, size = sizeof(text)/sizeof(text[0]);

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
        head = addNode(head, text[i]);
}

struct node* addNode(struct node* head, char s[])
{
    struct node* temp = malloc( sizeof(struct node) );
    strcpy(temp->s, s);
    temp->next = head;
    return temp;
}
```

I'm confused at the beginning part and how it initially links to the next.

- create struct node *head in main /*does head have adress?*/
- send string to addnode along with head/*if head is null what are we initially sending*/
- create and copy info to temp variable
- /*if head coming into addnode function has no adress whats in temp->next?*/
- return temp and assign it to head in main /*so after the first loop *head has an adress,inside that adress it points to struct node with "one" but what is *next for that node?*/

Comment: `NULL` is an address, quoting the C-FAQ: `there is a special value -- the "null pointer" -- which is distinguishable from all other pointer values and which is not the address of any object or function`.

Answer (score 0):

a single linked list normally is a pointer to the first element (usually called 'head'). every subsequent element of the list is linked over the next-pointer of the actual element. typically, the elements of the list (including head) are malloced.

so initialy head is NULL. you have an empty list.

add one element, you point head to that element, and the next points to NULL.

Now you have two implementation options. Append or prepend the next object.

If you append, you run thru the linked list to the end and let the last next-Pointer point to the new element. Here you have to consider that you are "appending" the very first element (having an empty head).

or you prepend (like in the example) the new element, making it the new head. so new's elemet next points to the old list (which starts with head, even if head is empty) and the new head bekomes the new element. Sideeffect, you reverse the order of elements.

when I work with lists, it is a good visualization for me, to paint boxes (malloc) and arrows (helping pointers like head, prev or last) on paper and connect the boxes with arrows (next-Pointer)

Answer (score -2):

A few strange things are going on. You are assigning a new node to the head, whilst head should always stay the same. What you want is to assign a new node to the next pointer of the last node with a pointer to NULL.

In your main:

```
struct node *head;
head->next=NULL; //Head points to nothing and is the last node

int i, size = sizeof(text)/sizeof(text[0]); //I think this goes well because size rounds to 3, should be optimized

for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    addNode(head, text[i]);
```

In yout addNode function:

```
addNode(struct node* head, char s[])
{
    struct node *iteratorNode = head;
    while (iteratorNode->next!=NULL) //search for last node
    {
        iteratorNode = iteratorNode->next;
    }    
    iteratorNode->next = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    iteratorNode = iteratorNode->next;
    iteratorNode->name = name;
    iteratorNode->next = NULL;     
}
```

Comment: "struct node *head; head->next=NULL;" will crash imidiately, because head is not initialized, so dereferencing is bad.

Comment: your add function REQUIRES, that you have a first (aka head) element, which in initial state is never the case, except you build a dummy head-element.

Comment: you changed the symantics of the programme, the OP has provided. His linked list will be a Stack (first in last out), yours is a pipe (first in first out)